# How to allocate memory for prime numbers

Tags: algorithms, space-complexity, primes

I was working on an algorithm to find prime numbers, and I needed to allocate memory for each prime number that I found so far. I will do a search up to N and need to allocate all memory in advance. I found the following : https://t5k.org/howmany.html . This gave me some  nice approximations for how many numbers I should allocate.

However the accurate approximations used Riemann zeta function and all seemed to be rather computationally expensive. I need a way to find the number of prime numbers under N that is both fast (O(log(N)) or constant preferably) and will never give a number back that is less then the number of prime numbers before N.

I could of course just ceil(take N/2) but I intend to allocate the absolute minimum of memory. As in my case space complexity is of essence.
Does anyone know an elegant solution?
Thanks in advance.

PS : right now I am using ceil(N/ln(N)) + 1000 as a temporary solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number

Comment: thx but your linking me back to what I already got in my link. if you can make some pseudo code that follows my given conditions I will accept

Comment: Your summary is not accurate.  There are approximations that are fairly accurate, do not use the Riemann zeta function, and are computationally fast to compute; and they can be found in the link I shared.

Comment: What's wrong with what you're using as a temporary solution?  It seems fine.  Using 1000 words of extra memory seems hardly worth worrying about.

Comment: yeah your wright,  in retrospective I think it's fine. The thing is it wasn't all that elegant :). but your right. If you give an answer stating that this issue is irrelevant and that this approximation will never give less than the number of primes I will approve

Comment: "I intend to allocate the absolute minimum of memory" is not possible as we don't have the exact expression of the number of primes.

Comment: "all seemed to be rather computationally expensive": for any serious $N$, the cost of evaluation of the bound will be completely negligible compared to the search itself (even computable at no cost at compile-time).

Comment: If you need *all* primes until $N$, a sieve is the most efficient. Then you have to allocate $N$ bits (which is probably more compact than the explicit list of primes themselves). As a byproduct of the sieve, you will know the exact number of primes.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion as it is very useful and you should probably write an answer. But I was experimenting with an alternative algorithm to search prime numbers, using witness numbers and was for recreational purposes not interested in using a sieve. Although you are of course right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you allocate space for
$$U = \max(N/(\ln(N) - 1.1), N/\ln(N) + 2000).$$

This will be quite close to the true number.  For instance, for $N=10^7$, it is only 1284 larger than the true number.  Using a few thousand extra words of memory is hardly worth worrying about.

Moreover, I expect that the chance that the true number of primes exceeds $U$ is either zero, or so small as to not be worth worrying about.  In particular, it is apparently known that the true number is less than $N/(\ln(N) - 1.1)$ for all $N \ge 60184$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function), and for $N < 60184$ I expect the true number will be less than $N/\ln(N) + 2000$.

Comment: In the first paragraph you give an upper bound. In the second paragraph you consider the chance that the upper bound will be exceeded. What?

Comment: @AndrejBauer, good point, I shouldn't have used the phrase "upper bound".  I have revised my answer to try to be clearer.  Thank you!

Comment: I hope you never write software that controls a nuclear power plant :-)